# AppleScript - echo into openssl AES encryption - is there a way to crack/snoop thru logs?

Tags: terminal, applescript, security, hacking, openssl

Don't know if this question is better off here, or in the Linux world...but I need a decent answer.. :)

I am using Applescript to pull data from fields in a spreadsheet or database, shove them directly into terminal for encryption.

My Applescript includes a line like:

```
echo "thisismydatastring and my saltbits"  | openssl aes-256-cbc -k thisismypassword -base64
```

My question:  is there a way one could filter thru log files to catch this plaintext instance of the password?

Is there a better way to prevent hacking?

If sending an "echo" into terminal is traceable, is there another way I could push something into Terminal where it doesn't hit any logs (and where AppleScript can get the results)?

Comment: Logs are one issue, protection against anybody running `ps aux` to see the command line is another...

Comment: Possible X Y problem? `http://xyproblem.info/ `

Comment: yes, ps aux is exactly one of my concerns.  However, i've run this both as a user and as root, and have been unable to see anything actually passing into terminal during this process..  How exactly would you propose sniffing it out with ps?

Comment: How would one prove or disprove whether Applescript is hiding actions from bash logs? Is there a way an Applescript can pass a command (say MD5 hash, or openssl AES-265-cbc command) without it hitting the bash history?

Comment: `ps l` will happily show any command line of commands currently running, so if an attacker runs it in a loop or at right moment they can read your password easily. And the command line is part of the openly accessible process table, so some lines of C code will extract the data as well.

Comment: You stated, "My Applescript includes a line like:" and I submit that you need to clarify how you're implementing `echo "thisismydatastring and my salt bits"  | openssl aes-256-cbc -k thisismypassword -base64` because if it's done in a `tell application "Terminal"` _block_ using the `do script` _command_, it is being written to `.bash_history`. However, if done in the AppleScript built-in `do shell script` _command_, it is not being logged anywhere because the `do shell script` _command_ uses a _non-interactive_ `shell`, and `HISTORY` is disabled in a _non-interactive_ `shell`. Continued...

Comment: You can use e.g. `set theResult to (do shell script "...")` and the _variable_ `theResult` will hold the info for further processing you want and done so without any logging for the reason stated in my first comment.

Comment: user3439894 - thx..  yes, we already use a "Set theResult to (do shell script....)" command, so it would seem (coupled with the fact that variables dies at the end of the shell) that this would pass thru without history.   It would seem that the only additional concern I'd have is whether or not "ps l" could snoop out the script as it goes by (even if it's a non-interactive shell)...  Any method to show or spy on this from a root level?  How can I actually replicate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overcome the password issue in my bash scripts by sourcing (including) another file with a predetermined variable already set.

For example.  Say you have a "config" file  `~/config.conf` and in it you assign some variables:

```
# Config file for MyScript.sh

$user = Me
$pass = S3cr3t5!
```

In your script you source the file so you can use the variables you defined:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /Path/to/config.conf

stuff= "thisismydatastring and my saltbits"

echo  $stuff | openssl aes-256-cbc -k $pass -base64
```

Personally, I like to keep the line that executes the command as clean as possible using variables (like `stuff` in the example above) so that it's easier to see what the command is doing and consequently easier to debug.

Is this safe from prying eyes?  Yes, for the most part.  You can set the permissions so that only the user can read and write the file and deny it to everyone else:

```
chmod 600 config.conf
```

Anyone snooping through logs (which is your question) won't be able to see the plain text passwords.

Comment: it would seem to me that a separate fail with the name & pwd would actually be a less secure model, as it would be rather trivial to 'unerase' such a file at a later time, open it, and find the data...   and root can generally circumvent any permissions configurations....

Comment: I don't see how it would be less secure. If your fear is that *root* can see your passwords, they will see it regardless of where you try to store it (same file or different) unless of course you can (if you have rights to do so) make the file immutable (as is the case in FreeBSD).  If your storage is an SSD, it's no longer trivial to unease.  You delete it and it's gone.

Comment: This is also a very common practice in Web development where passwords to things like MySQL databases are stored in off site directories unavailable to the web daemon but obviously available to anyone with rights (obviously root)

Comment: Allan,  WRT variables in the Mac *nix environ, does the variable itself die at the end of the command, or is it possible for someone to call it again at a later point in time?

Comment: Just tested it...it dies.  From my understanding, to make it "persistent" after the script executes is to `export` the variable.